# Alternative to DataReader and Database Updating in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am starting to learn my ropes with MVC, and so far so good with the exception of models. I believed that one could call these models directly and make changes to the database directly. Right now I have the Model variables, and in the Controller I use a DataReader method (SqlCommand) and manual queries to update the DB, but I find this archaic as in example in Django I can just write the models and call the DB to it or update accordingly. I guess there must be a way, and my question is regarding that. Is there such a way? (Like... modelVariable.Save or modelVariable.Get(ID) and it binds to the database?)

Comment: If I understand, you're looking for an ORM. Heard about Entity framework, maybe ?

Comment: You are looking for [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework)

Comment: *welp* how did I miss that. I glossed over EF before and didn't pay attention to it. I see its very "dependant" on Visual Studio tools, which reminds me a bit of DataSets and the like which I hated with a passion. Is it similar to that?

Comment: LinQ lets you query your database directly through C#. Gone are the days of going to SQL Server and creating sp's for every query that you need.